# How to prevent an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this case?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

The question is:
given a string: aaaBBB

I need to print: a3B3
(counting occurrences of each letter in a given string).

I tried the following:

```
        String x = "aaaBBB";
        char[] c = x.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int count = 1;
        System.out.println(c.length);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                if (c[i] == c[i+1]) {
                    count++;
                } else {
                    sb.append(c[i]).append(count);
                    count = 1;
                }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
```

I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception, for my last iteration, when I check c[i] with c[i+1] (pretty obvious, because the index i+1 doesn't exist).

I'd want to know some ways to avoid getting this exception, without changing the if condition.
Might sound like poor research, but I've been trying this for quite some time now, but not able to get through, before posting it here.

Comment: (c[i] == c[i+1]) this will cause problems in your last iteration, because at that point, i is the maximal index, and i + 1 is the out of bounds.

Comment: you could change this: for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) to this: for (int i = 0; i < (c.length-1); i++)

Comment: @Stultuske, you have a valid point, but if we use c.length-1 as you suggested, we will not get our expected output

Comment: then you'll need to change your if statement

Comment: @RudeWastefulTelevision if an approach is wrong you don't try to solve it by **not** changing a part, you should just take a different approach to the problem :) I mean, this is a weird way of counting occurrences of letters in a string. Do you have a good reason for not wanting to change the condition?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, yup, agreed, I thought there'd be a way to control the last iteration, by using some checks for it, but it seems it's not that easy as I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- assign the first character to an independent variable.
- when no longer equal to subsequent characters. Add to the string with that character and count.
- then reset that character and count to the next one and 1.
- when all characters are exhausted, add the final character and count.

```
String x = "aaaaBBBcDDDDD";
char[] c = x.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

int count = 1;
char ch = c[0];
for (int i = 1; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i] == ch) {
            count++;
        } else {
            sb.append(ch).append(count);
            ch = c[i];
            count = 1;
        }
}
sb.append(ch).append(count);
System.out.println(sb);
```

Prints

```
a4B3c1D5
```